# Creating a java launch configuration based on a runtime debug instance

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am running a complex j2ee application that requires a long time to start up.
When debugging it, I can obviously see the call stack, threads, the variables and so on...
I am trying to avoid restarting the application for every change I do, which takes time, and simply run this configuration, which simulate the runtime environment that I see when I debug.
Is there a tool or a way, to create a launch configuration based this debug instance? I would expect from this launch configuration to create all the variables and the thread...

Comment: If the changes are small then Eclipse Hot-Swap would work. Also can you share little more.. as to what is that taking most of the time to start up or other details @supportGuy

Comment: Most Eclipse Java EE connectors (talking to the Java EE server) make an effort to minimize the amount of work necessary when changing a file, but this is implementation dependent.  Note that complex maven manipulation of war files may result in the connector not being able to take these shortcuts resulting in the full, slow redeploy.   Read the documentation carefully - you might need to work differently than you do now.